# Client sends a UDP Packet to a server over the internet, but it could not recieve any UDP packages from the server

Tags: c#, sockets, udp

Client sends a UDP Packet to a server over the internet, but it could not recieve any UDP packages from the server.

Server has a valid IP and I'm connected to the internet via ADSL

### In both server and client these codes are used:

Send Packet:

```
Socket sock1 = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);                    
IPEndPoint iep1 = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(txt_IP.Text), Convert.ToInt32(txt_SendPort.Text));
byte[] data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("UDP");

sock1.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.Broadcast, true);
sock1.SendTo(data, iep1);
```

---

Receive Packet:

```
Console.WriteLine("Listening to the port {0}", PortNumber);
sock1 = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);
IPEndPoint iep = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, PortNumber);
sock1.Bind(iep);
EndPoint ep = (EndPoint)iep;
byte[] data1 = new byte[100];
int recv = sock1.ReceiveFrom(data1, ref ep);
sock1.Close();
String str_Data = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data1, 0, recv);
String str_IP = ep.ToString().Substring(0, ep.ToString().IndexOf(":"));
Console.WriteLine("Received Succesfully: {0} - {1}", str_Data, str_IP);
```

---

My NIC IP is 169.254.254.5, But the server shows my IP is 188.136.170.14 and send the reply to 188.136.170.14 (188.136.170.14 is the IP of access point). How can I change the code in the server side to send bank the packet to the client correctly?

Comment: try using a network profiler like tcpview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By access point, is that your router? You said ADSL, so I'll assume it is.

Your router spans 2 networks. The Internet is on 1 side in the form of your ISP & your internal network is on the other. This is why the server sees your router IP, not your NIC IP.

You need to define a port forward rule on the router to send inbound traffic on the port you're using onwards to your PC. Don't use broadcast either - this is for contacting a number of NICs on a subnet.

Strictly speaking this is more of network issue rather than a programming one.

Answer (score 0):

The *SocketOptionName.Broadcast* is not used on internet. UDP via internet will only work with peer-peer.

Comment: My NIC IP is 169.254.254.5, But the server shows my IP is 188.136.170.14 and send the reply to 188.136.170.14 (188.136.170.14 is the IP of access point). How can I change the code in the server side to send bank the packet to the client correctly?